# CloudKit Subscription Woes

Tags: cloudkit, cksubscription

I am struggling with the following subscription:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "gc_alias != %@ AND distanceToLocation:fromLocation:(%K,%@) < %f",
                                self.localPlayer!.alias!,
                                "location",
                                self.currentLocation!,
                                10)


    let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Player", predicate: predicate, options: .FiresOnRecordCreation)
    subscription.zoneID = nil

    let notification = CKNotificationInfo()
    notification.alertBody = "Nearby Player within Range!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    subscription.notificationInfo = notification

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    let publicDb = container.publicCloudDatabase

    publicDb.saveSubscription(subscription) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("SUBSCRIBED SUCCESS")
            print(result)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "subscribed")
        }
    }
```

Basically, when a new Player record is created or updated I log the user's location.

I want user A to be notified via Push when user B creates or updates their Player record and is within 10KM.

I believe I have the push permissions setup correctly in my app (user is prompted to confirm this before their sub is created, for example).

No pushes arriveth. Any ideas? Am I suffering from some fundamental CK misconception?

Comment: Could you add the code where you create the CK record and where you register for notifications?

Comment: distanceToLocation:fromLocation:() returns metres not kilometres. You need to pass 10000 instead of 10.

Comment: Diegog FTW! Meters seemed to clinch it! There's misinformation on this on the web, surprisingly. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be registering for push notifications:

[iOS Developer Library: Subscribing to Record Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/SubscribingtoRecordChanges/SubscribingtoRecordChanges.html)

> Saving subscriptions to the database doesn’t automatically configure your app to receive notifications when a subscription fires. CloudKit uses the Apple Push Notification service (APNs) to send subscription notifications to your app, so your app needs to register for push notifications to receive them.

According to [Hacking with Swift: Delivering notifications with CloudKit push messages: CKSubscription and saveSubscription](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/33/8/delivering-notifications-with-cloudkit-push-messages-cksubscript) you should:

> Go to AppDelegate.swift and put this code into the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

And

> For the sake of completion, you could optionally also catch the didReceiveRemoteNotification message sent to your app delegate, which is called if a push message arrives while the app is running. Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let pushInfo = userInfo as? [String: NSObject] {
        let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: pushInfo)

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "What's that Whistle?", message: notification.alertBody, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))

        if let nc = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            if let vc = nc.visibleViewController {
                vc.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am registering for notifications elsewhere. What I want to know is, will this type of subscription work for notifying player A that player B has updated their Player object in CK with a location that is within 10KM of their current location. In my dashboard, with two accounts on two test devices, I still see only one Subscription Type.

Comment: Awarding bounty to didgog for his observation above about meters vs km.